# Installation of Advantage ODBC 64bit driver

Tags: advantage-database-server

After installing the V10 64-bit driver from here http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=15 on 64bit Windows 7 Professional and trying to connect I get the following error messge:

"ODBC -call failed [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (#0)"

When I click "Check DLLs" I get an error message saying that the following DLLs were not found adsodbc.dll

I have tried uninstall, re-install, the adsodbc.dll file is not on the computer anywhere but there is a file called adsodbc64.dll I have tried copying and renaming this with no success.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 3):

I believe the "Check DLLs" message is in error and a red haring in regards to the base issue.  I too have a similar setup and see that it is looking for the adsodbc.dll rather then adsodbc64.dll.  But in my situation I am able to connect.

The error message you get is often due to a mistype of the name (i.e. mydsn123 vs mydsn23).

It may also be due to the application attempting to use the ODBC driver.  For example, is the application attempting to use the ODBC driver actually a 32-bit application that would be looking for a 32-bit ODBC DSN using C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe rather then the 64-bit c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe... Names are confusing here, where the system32 = 64-bit and syswow64 = 32-bit.

Comment: Edgar is correct, the CheckDLLs dialog is looking for the 32bit DLLs.  This is a known issue with the 64bit ODBC client installation.  The 64bit ODBC driver should still work fine.

Comment: Peter / Edgar  appreciate your response.  I have managed to use the 64 bit driver on a client site connecting from 32bit Access 2007 on a Windows 7 b4 bit machine to data on a 64 bit server I do get the check dlls "red herring" but can connect no problem.

On my own machine I have Windows 7 64 Bit running Office 2010 64 bit and am connecting to a 32bit server through Virtual PC.

If I try to install the 32bit driver it does not appear when I try to add a new DSN.  I have also tried connecting to the ADS sample data on the local C drive but still get the same issue.

Comment: I think I will try uninstalling Office 2010 64 bit and reinstall the 32 bit version - illogical and frustrating but I am running out of ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is that Windows7 x64 supports only 32bit ODBC drivers. Checkout
[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/1c63e3ae-e001-4066-9eac-ad9162116603)

Comment: netme thanks for your response but the link is relates to IIS and I don't think is relevant in this case